# How to sync Readme.io file with Gitlab? Getting error: unknown option '--key=xxxx" error

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, readme.io

I am trying to sync my readme.io API doc with my Gitlab for automatic updates, however I am getting the following error after I run the pipeline.

> error: unknown option '--key=rdme_xxxxxxx....'

This is inside my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: node:14
sync-via-rdme:
  script:
    - npx -y rdme@7.5.0 openapi file.json --key=xxxxxx --id=xxxxxx
```

When I run it using this command locally via VScode it works but changes are not pushed into the readme.io API Reference when I do it via Git. I want to be able to do it via Git.

```
npx -y rdme@7.5.0 openapi file.json --key=rdme_xxxxx  --id=xxxxx
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Acording to https://docs.readme.com/docs/rdme#example-syncing-an-openapi-definition your CI Yaml file should be something like:

```
name: Sync OpenAPI definition to ReadMe

# Run workflow for every push to the `main` branch
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout this repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Run GitHub Action to sync OpenAPI file at [path-to-file.json]
      - name: GitHub Action
        # We recommend specifying a fixed version, i.e. @7.5.0
        # Docs: https://docs.github.com/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-versioned-actions
        uses: readmeio/rdme@7.5.0
        with:
          rdme: openapi file.json --key=API_KEY --id=API_DEFINITION_ID
```